# NextJS import images in MDX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I tried a official NextJS MDX-Blog example.
https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/tree/master/examples/next

But what I'm not able to figure out is how do I setup the NextJS config to load images via webpack?

```
import img from "./image.jpg"

## Hallo Blogwelt

![My own Image]({img})
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the `/public` directory to hold your images. For example, if you add an image at `/public/image.jpg`, you can reference the image in your blog post like this:

```
![Alt Text](/image.jpg)
```

Edit: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#local-images

Comment: starting with Next v11, this is not necessary. You can [import images from any location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68453264/6908282)

Answer (score 4):

Imagine your `next.config.js` as something to append to an existing `webpack.config` behind the scenes. You won't have direct access to the webpack but you can extend it.

So in order to load images you'll need an appropriate image loader.

I found [next-images](https://github.com/arefaslani/next-images) easiest to use:

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages({
  webpack(config, options) {
    return config
  }
})
```

then you can import:

```
import Img from "./image.jpg"
```

Answer (score 3):

Hey thanks for the tip!

It's been a while since June and a gave it another try today and now it's working like expected from me.

1. I took the [MDX/Next Example](https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/tree/master/examples/next)
2. Edited the next.config.js like so:

   ```
   const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
   const images = require('remark-images');
   const emoji = require('remark-emoji');
   const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');

   const withMDX = require('@zeit/next-mdx')({
     extension: /\.mdx?$/,
     options: {
       mdPlugins: [images, emoji]
     }
   });

   module.exports = withPlugins([
    [
      withMDX,
      {
        pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'md', 'mdx']
      }
    ],
      [optimizedImages]
    ]);
   ```

Now it works exactly like expected and in a Markdown file within the pages folder I'm able to do something like this:

```
import Layout from '../../components/Layout'
import Image from './catimage.jpg'


# Hey guys this is the heading of my post!

<img src={Image} alt="Image of a cat" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I'm late, but with Next v11 you can directly import images.

That being said, you can add custom loaders for Webpack to modify your mdx files and use a custom component to process the image. e.g.:

```js
// save this somewhere such as mdxLoader and
// add it to your webpack configuration
const replaceAll = require("string.prototype.replaceall");

module.exports = function (content, map, meta) {
  return replaceAll(
    map
    content,
    /\!\[(.*)\]\((.+)\)/g,
    `<NextImage alt="$1" src={require('$2').default} />`
  );
};
```

and process it:

```
// and reference this in your MDX provider
const components = {
  NextImage: (props: any) => {
    return <Image alt={props.alt || "Image"} {...props} />;
  },
};
```

Now you can use markdown flavored images in your posts!

```
![my image](./image.png)
```

Include the `./` relative prefix, however.

Comment: found this article which can be of help: https://noahflk.com/blog/next-image-optimization

Answer (score 0):

I'm building a Next.js blog with [`MDX-Bundler`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdx-bundler). It allows you to use a remark plugin called [remark-mdx-images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remark-mdx-images) which converts markdown flavored images into JSX images.

Below is an example configuration to get it to work

```js
const {code} = await bundleMDX(source, {
  cwd: '/posts/directory/on/disk',
  xdmOptions: options => {
    options.remarkPlugins = [...(options.remarkPlugins ?? []), remarkMdxImages]

    return options
  },
  esbuildOptions: options => {
    options.outdir = '/public/directory/on/disk/img'
    options.loader = {
      ...options.loader,
      '.jpg': 'file'
    }
    options.publicPath = '/img/'
    options.write = true

    return options
  }
})
```

You can check out the following resources for detailed explanation on how to do it.

1. [Images with MDX-Bundler](https://www.alaycock.co.uk/2021/04/images-with-mdx-bundler)
2. [How I built the new notjust.dev platform with NextJS](https://www.notjust.dev/blog/2021-06-21-how-i-built-the-new-notjustdev-platoform-using-nextjs#:%7E:text=copy%20all%20the%20images%20at%20build%20time)

Comment: [remark-images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remark-images) is also a similar package that can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the [`@next/mdx`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/using-mdx#nextmdx) package you can use the [`<Image />`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#local-images) component Next.js provides:

```
// pages/cute-cat.mdx

import Image from "next/image";
import cuteCat from "./cute-cat.jpg";

# Cute cat

This is a picture of a cute cat

<Image src={cuteCat} />
```