# I can't reference an image in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a React component that's being used in Next.js page:

**/pages/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Layout from "../src/hoc/Layout/Layout";
import Main from "../src/components/Main/Main";

const Index = () => (
   <Layout>
       <Main />
   </Layout>
);
export default Index
```

In Main.js I have the following code

```
import macbookIphone from '../../assets/images/mac-iphone.jpg';
```

I get the following error

> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
> configured to process this file. See
> https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code omitted for this
> binary file)

I tried doing the following

In **next-config.js**

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages()
```

I'm still getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to import it? Can't you just do `<img src='../../assets/images/mac-iphone.jpg' />`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

/public/favicon/mail.png

=> "/favicon/mail.png" will work

Answer (score 44):

From Next.js v11 onwards, you can do what you were doing without any additional config:

```js
import macbookIphone from '../../assets/images/mac-iphone.jpg';

<Image src={macbookIphone} />

// or

<img src={macbookIphone.src} />
```

Ref: [`next/image`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)

For earlier versions if you wish to import images instead of putting them in public directory, then you can configure `file-loader` or `url-loader`.

Comment: check out the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68429232/6908282) if you'd like to use markdown flavored images

Comment: found this article which can be of help: https://noahflk.com/blog/next-image-optimization

Comment: the .src did the trick for me, thanks!

Answer (score 25):

Please see 
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

> Next.js can serve static files, like images, under a folder called public in the root directory. Files inside public can then be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (/).

Comment: Hello. Do you know how can I get content from the Public folder into dynamic pages, i.e - dynamic[id].js ?

Answer (score 11):

At least in our project, we use require for images instead of import. Our next config looks similar to yours.

Try the following and see if it helps:

```
const macbookIphone = require('../../assets/images/mac-iphone.jpg');
```

You can then use your image as the src like this:

```
<img src={macbookIphone}/>
```

Comment: Hello. Do you know how can I get content from the Public folder into dynamic pages, i.e - dynamic[id].js ?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Mixing require with import does not bode well. If you use ES6 style, you'll need to stick to it.

Answer (score 5):

Using images in Next.js is a bit different:

All your static assets like images must be placed in the `public` directory.

- If your code is under ***src*** directory, i.e `<app-name>/src/pages , <app-name>/src/components, ...` then your public folder must be outside of the src directory. Public folder cannot be under src as `<app-name>/src/public.`
  In this case your public directory must be under `<app-name>/public`.
- If your code is *not* under ***src*** directory, i.e `<app-name>/pages, <app-name>/components, ...` then your public directory should be under `<app-name>/public`

Once you have that sorted, directly refer to the file in the `<Image />` component provided by `next/image` as:

```
import Image from "next/image"
<Image src="/sample-image.png" width="64" height="64" />
```

or

```
import Image from "next/image"
import sampleImage from "<file-path>"

<Image src={sampleImage} width="64" height="64" />
```

provided you have a file under *public/sample-image.png*

If you have an image URL, directly provide it to the 'src' prop.

Find descriptive examples related to layouts at: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/image-component

References:

1. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving
2. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image
3. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization
4. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/src-directory

Answer (score 3):

You can import images by using `next-images`

**Step 1**

`npm install --save next-images`

or

`yarn add next-images`

**Step 2**

```
// Create next.config.js
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages()
```

**For Typescript**

```
// Add following line in next-env.d.ts
/// <reference types="next-images" />
```

Restart your server and now you can import your images like

`import img1 from "assets/images/cover_images/blog_1.png"`

https://github.com/twopluszero/next-images

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me like this, but putting the file in the public folder:

```jsx
<Image width={150} height={100} src={'/punkieslogo.png'} alt="Picture of the author" />
```

Comment: pro tip: you can add code fences to format the codes

Answer (score 0):

you cannot access images in Next.js like in React.js unless they are stored in 'public' folder.

Answer (score 0):

**you can import image then you should use it easily**

```
import pic1 from "../public/assets/12093.jpg";

 <Image src={pic1} alt="photo" fill={true} />
```

**it's work for me :)**

Answer (score 0):

- add your images inside **public** folder
- for organizing add **images** folder inside **public** folder
- if you're using nextjs **Image** component, add **src** attribute
- the root folder for images or icons is by default **/public**
- so start from the folder you want inside public, like this : **src="/images/yourpicture.png"**
- Don't forget to add the extension .png .jpeg ...