# Failed to parse src error when importing an image in Next.js

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I'm trying to import an image in Next.js but I get this error. I don't know what's the problem, could someone here help me about this?
The image is located in public folder, this is the Error I get when I run the server.

> Error: Failed to parse src "../public/logo.png" on `next/image`, if
> using relative image it must start with a leading slash "/" or be an
> absolute URL (http:// or https://)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question: [I can't reference an image in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546370/i-cant-reference-an-image-in-next-js)? Just reference your image as `/logo.png`.

Comment: Try to use require in src. eg: src={require('../public/logo.png')}

Answer (score 23):

Whatever is found in **`Next.js'`** `public` folder can be accessed directly with an `/`. It can also be accessed by your end-users if `/logo.png` is typed on their search bar.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

> Next.js can serve static files, like images, under a folder called public in the root directory. Files inside public can then be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (/).
> For example, if you add an image to public/me.png, the following code will access the image:

This ought to do it:

```
 <Image src="/logo.png" alt="logo" width="64" height="64" />
```

Assuming your project's structure is the following:

```
root
|
├───public
│   └───logo.png
```

Answer (score 2):

oh to solve that error you just need to include a / at the beginning of ../public/logo.png   to get this /../public/logo.png