# I am getting this Error while importing image from asset folder in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

> I have created react app its working fine but when i added all this app file in shopify app where next js exit so i am getting this error ,

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from "react";
 import bag from "../assets/bag.jpg";
export const ProductsContext = createContext();
const ProductsContextProvider = (props) => {
const [products] = useState([
{id:1, name: 'Bag', image: bag, price: 300,    status: 'hot'}
 ]);
     return (
 <ProductsContext.Provider value = {{products : [...products]}}>
  {props.children}
 </ProductsContext.Provider>
 )
 }
 export default ProductsContextProvider;
```

> this is my error

> ┃ error - ./pages/assets/bag.jpg 1:0
> ┃ Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
> ┃ You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> ┃ (Source code omitted for this binary file)
>
> this is my next.config.js

```
const { parsed: localEnv } = require("dotenv").config();
const webpack = require("webpack");
 const apiKey = JSON.stringify(process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY);
  module.exports = {
   webpack: (config) => {
   const env = { API_KEY: apiKey };
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(env));
   // Add ESM support for .mjs files in webpack 4
   config.module.rules.push({
     test: /\.mjs$/,
     include: /node_modules/,
      type: "javascript/auto",
    });

return config;
  },

 };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't reference an image in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546370/i-cant-reference-an-image-in-next-js)

Answer (score 0):

change the path of the image to  `import bag from "./assets/bag.jpg";` if the assets in the public folder

Comment: No i have tried this but i am also getting same issue

Comment: can you show us the ProductsContext component and try to get console.log of the object pass to this component

Comment: Please help me how can i solve this error

Comment: can you put it in the component as a path without an import thing ? like this
/assets/bag.jpg